# How can i remove the border from an image attribute that's get from an input?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem and i don't get rid of it so help me. I have an input IMG and i have a script that shows me the selected image. But when the input is empty, the image attribute shows a black border. can't get rid of the black border. it's very frustrating. so how can i remove the border or image attribute if there is no input selected? help me!

```
`<img id="uploadPreview" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;" />
```

```
<input id="imgInp" type="file" name="myPhoto" onchange="PreviewImage();" />


function PreviewImage() {
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);

    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
        document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
    };
};
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe style the image line with something like:

```
border-width:0px;
border:none;
```

That should remove any kind of border.

Or add an

```
display:none
```

to hide the image completely.

Answer (score 0):

check everytime before append image source that the image value is empty or not. if empty do nothing else append image atr or source .

as you are appending nothing on image attr its showing that border that means no image or img url not found.

```js
  const loadFile = function(event) {
    const output = document.getElementById('output');
    output.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
    output.onload = function() {
      URL.revokeObjectURL(output.src) // free memory
    }
  };
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="loadFile(event)">
<img id="output"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

add style to hide image first

```
#uploadPreview{
display:none;
}

function PreviewImage() {
    var oFReader = new FileReader();
    oFReader.readAsDataURL(document.getElementById("uploadImage").files[0]);
if(oFReader == "" || oFReader== null){
  alert("image is empty")
}else{
    oFReader.onload = function (oFREvent) {
        document.getElementById("uploadPreview").src = oFREvent.target.result;
        document.getElementById("uploadPreview").style = "display:block";
}
        };
    };
```